# 400 Bad request when filtering data using the autogenerated ID column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, error, http-400-bad-request

Been hitting my head and have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have couple columns in a list and I want to update the Column field by choosing the ID field. Below is the URL that I generate but throws a 400 bad request error.

`/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Resourcing%20Entries')/items?$filter=ID%20eq%2019852`

Here you can see I am trying to filter the list with ID = 19852. Another thing I would like to point is that I created another test list on SP and tested the code that got from [here](https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/create-retrieve-update-and-delete-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-and-jquery/) and it somehow works.. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.. If you'd like I can paste the whole API call below..

Any suggestions would really be helpful.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? Also, please post the complete error message you are getting while calling this API.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this below endpoints:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Resourcing Entries')/items?$select=ID&$filter=ID eq 19852
```

**Note**: You need to use the **Display Name** of the list (Name you see on list view page).

Or you can directly get the list item if you are getting the item using SharePoint OOTB ID column like:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Resourcing Entries')/items(19852)
```